# How can I convert this table to DIV's?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
        <tr>
          <td width="100" height="110"><a href="Frankrijk.html"><img src="Images/Landen/Frankrijk.gif" alt="Frankrijk" width="100" height="67" border="0"></a></td>
          <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="100" height="110"><a href="Spanje.html"><img src="Images/Landen/Spanje.gif" alt="Spanje" width="100" height="67" border="0"></a></td>
          <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="100" height="110"><a href="Zuid_Afrika.html"><img src="Images/Landen/ZuidAfrika.gif" alt="Zuid Afrika" width="100" height="67" border="0"></a></td>
          <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="100" height="110"><a href="Argentinie.html"><img src="Images/Landen/Argentinie.gif" alt="Italië" width="100" height="67" border="0"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="detailText" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><a href="Frankrijk.html">Frankrijk</a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td class="detailText" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><a href="Spanje.html">Spanje</a></td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td class="detailText" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><a href="Zuid_Afrika.html">Zuid-Afrika</a></td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td class="detailText" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><a href="Argentinie.html">Argentinië</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td height="110"><a href="Chili.html"><img src="Images/Landen/Chili.gif" alt="Chili" width="100" height="67" border="0"></a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td height="110"><a href="Australie.html"><img src="Images/Landen/Australie.gif" alt="Italië" width="100" height="67" border="0"></a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td height="110"><a href="Italie.html"><img src="Images/Landen/Italie.gif" alt="Italië" width="100" height="67" border="0"></a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td height="110">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="detailText" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><a href="Chili.html">Chili</a></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td class="detailText" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><a href="Australie.html">Australië</a></td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td class="detailText" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><a href="Italie.html">Italië</a></td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td class="detailText" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But I want to convert this to Div's and place them all next to each other.
In my test to change them to Divs, I've used the following CSS.

```
.OverviewContainer{Margin:35px auto;text-align:center;display:inline;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.OverviewPicture{width:130px;height:120px;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
.OverviewText{width:130px;font:12px arial;color:#ffffff;line-height:16px;letter-spacing:.1em;}
```

Comment: Why do you want to turn this decent-looking table into div soup in the first place? Is it not tabular data?

Comment: Where is your question? What part of this task is giving you trouble? If you want to turn it into divs, *just do it*. Start writing markup. Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Get rid of these ancient attributes: `valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" align="center"`. It's 2012 and we have CSS.

Comment: Ugh. Upvoters, **come on**. This isn't a question, there is not even an *implied* question, and it's *the very definition* of too localized. This should be closed, not upvoted. This is a thinly veiled request to get somebody else to do the work for him.

Comment: @Pekka: I don't know about "decent-looking" table. I don't see any table semantics going on.

Comment: It's often far more useful to tell us the *big picture* goal (like @Pekka says - *why?*), then you can get guidance on how to accomplish that goal.  This is a very specific technical question that doesn't necessarily make sense, but if you tell us *why*, then it might.

Comment: @meagar - These hats seem to be causing the blind upvoting. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159599/is-winter-bash-making-users-upvote-downvote-and-answer-randomly-to-earn-caps

Comment: @Paul true. (That's why I said "decent" not "good" :) Adding proper semantics might be the best way to go here

Comment: @user1921770: could you save your `<div>`-based code into JSFiddle.net so that we can see its results easily, and describe both what you expect it to do, & what it's actually doing?

Comment: I was trying to clean up my mothers site that I made for her. So that it will be easier to add items to the site. But the page that I mentioned above doesn't get update much so after reading all of this, I believe it will be best to stick with the table here.
I'm not trying to let anyone do the work for me. I'm just not experienced with building websites. This is just for helping my mother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that I also think this is a fairly poor question and might very well just be "a thinly veiled request to get somebody else to do the work" (as @meagar put it) it is easy enough to answer. Also, as @Pekka already mentioned, its best to use tables for tabular data.

HTML

```
<div class="OverviewContainer">
    <a class="OverviewPicture" href="Chili.html">
        <img src="Images/Landen/Chili.gif" alt="Chili">
    </a>
    <a class="OverviewText" href="Chili.html">Chili</a>
</div>

<div class="OverviewContainer">
    <a class="OverviewPicture" href="Australie.html">
        <img src="Images/Landen/Australie.gif" alt="Australie">
    </a>
    <a class="OverviewText" href="Australie.html">Australië</a>
</div>

<div class="OverviewContainer">
    <a class="OverviewPicture" href="Italie.html">
        <img src="Images/Landen/Italie.gif" alt="Italië">
    </a>
    <a class="OverviewText" href="Italie.html">Italië</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.OverviewContainer{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.OverviewPicture{
    width: 100px;
}

.OverviewText{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}​
```

​

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?  Is there a specific problem with this answer?